# Counting how many cells exist in one column but not the other

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi,

I have a list of items in column A, and another list of items in column B. I'd like to count the number of cells that are present in column A but NOT in column B. I've managed to do this by creating another column (column D) that uses the MATCH function to match column A to B, then I use another COUNTIF function to count the N/A's.

Is there a way I can do this in one function rather then having to create an extra column that matches?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Read about the new `LET` function - there you can combine multiple steps in one function.

Comment: Yes, there is. Will there be duplicates in either column?

Comment: no duplicates within a single column no

Comment: how can I use the LET function with the MATCH function? LET(variable, MATCH(A2, B:B, 0), variable2, MATCH(A3, B:B, 0) ... for the whole A column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it simply like this:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,A2:A5)>=1,1,0))
```

What does it mean?

The ranges I used:

- `A2:A5` : I'm looking for the values in column "A", from row 2 to 5.
- `$B$2:$B$7` : I'm looking for those values in this fixed range in column "B".

Explanation of the used worksheet functions:

```
COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,A2:A5) : how many times does the value appear?
IF(COUNTIF(...)>=1,1,0)  : if it appears, set 1, otherwise 0.
SUM(IF(...))             : take the sum of all those 1 values.
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'COUNTA' function for column A. This function counts all cells that are not empty in the range you select.